# Open ports in Ubuntu 13.10 server

Tags: networking, ubuntu, firewall, iptables

Im setting up a realtime gameserver fps-game, and then i need to configure ports.

Just to mention, i will setup multiple servers for this game on the same ip address,
which means i must open multiple ports, e.g range 27900-27950. I asume i should open the UDP. These ports above will be allowed and rest could i block when setting up firewall.

Would be nice if there's some script which would ensure
these ports are open automatically after an reboot, i guess ubuntu use
the default settings and the ports would be disabled after an reboot?

The server itself are supose to stay on a server-provider or on a local LAN.
Would there be something you should configure ip range on like 0.0.0.0 which will get the ip automatically when you set the network cable in?

I've looked into "ufw" "iptables". Should i go from there, or where should i start?

Sorry if this is very unclear, im new into linux.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Server with ufw installed, takes care about iptables by itself. You only need to add a rule to ufw allowing tcp/udp/both and it keeps until you delete it, no matter if you reboot the server.

For example, this line open the default SSH server port: sudo ufw allow 22

You can see your already opened ports typing: sudo ufw status verbose

[UFW Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/firewall.html)